# Spring Cloud: UI/Client on the same service as the gateway?

Tags: java, spring-cloud

Good day.

I am studying the microservices approach to building applications by utilizing Spring Cloud stack.

Some setup examples on the web and JHipster have their UI/Client part on the same service as the gateway.

My current setup has a gateway as a separate service and ui/client as also a separate service. Is this considered a correct approach?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Deniss